# tkinter issue in python on Linux host

Tags: python

Hi I am getting the following error while running one of my python script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

Error:

> _tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window"

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. Is this the only code in your script?

Comment: I am running this code on Linux machine using python 2.7.2. On window machine it's working fine.

Comment: I believe you, I am on Linux too, Gentoo distribution 4.9.16 with Python 2.7.12. What is your Tkinter version? `import Tkinter; print Tkinter.TkVersion`

Comment: Interesting.For me a window appeared and got crashed in less than one second with the error msg.
Traceback (most recent call last):File "python/v2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 163, in __call__
    manager.show()
  File "python/v2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 610, in show
  self.canvas.manager.window.attributes('-topmost', 1)
  File "python/v2.7.2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1493, in wm_attributes
    return self.tk.call(args)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window"

Comment: What did you change anything for it to do that?

Comment: Nothing earlier I posted only last line of the error msg. In my last comment I posted the complete error msg.

Comment: Any luck on this ?

Comment: Because `matplotlib` seems to use the `Tkinter` framework for its backend GUI window manager, maybe try to test only the `Tkinter` installation on your box first, before doing anything with `matplotlib` related. Maybe test your `Tkinter` module with the Simple Hello World Program https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program

Comment: Tried only Tkinter and it's working fine.

Comment: Seems some conflict between matlplotlib and tkinter module.I removed tkinter and keep the matplotlib and it start to work